# How To change the background color of a container using the Hex format?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the momentics IDE (native SDK).

I want to change the background color of a container using C++. But unfortunately, relating to this [[link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__color.html)], you only can define it like below :

```
**Creating a color in C++:**
Color c1 = Color::fromRGBA(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
Color c2 = Color::fromARGB(0xff996633);
```

For the color, I want to use the hex format ("#xxxxxx"). Any one can guide me on this ?

Comment: Are you just looking for code to convert a string beginning with #, followed by 6 hexadecimal digits, into an int value?  QString will do all of that, look at the mod and toInt methods.

Answer (score 2):

`Color c2 = Color::fromARGB(0xff996633);` is using hex the `0x is c++ representation of a hex code`. ff is the A component, 99 is the R, 66 is the G and 33 is the B

So if you want to use the hex value #000099 with no alpha

then it would be

```
Color::fromARGB(0x00000099)
```

The following code will convert a string to a hex value, you will need to remove the # from the string before hand however, and then can pass the string into the buffer object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() { 

    std::string hexString("#ffffff");
    hexString.erase(hexString.begin());

    std::istringstream buffer(hexString);

    int value;

    buffer >> std::hex >> value;

    std::cout << std::hex << value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand, but how should I convert a string to an int when I will have for example "#FFFFFF" ?

Comment: Added code that will convert a string to hex, you will need to remove the # from the front of the string however beforehand

Comment: Ok, I'm testing it!! just one thing, the "std::hex" does have any particular effect ? because I want to create a function that should return the int result value and used it.

Comment: I tried, but it gives me the following error: "invalid operands of types 'std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)' and 'int' to binary 'operator<<'"

Comment: @user2072762 you should be able to use the int directly, it should only matter when it comes to reading it, not what the value actually looks like, so just return value;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49130/discussion-between-const-ref-and-user2072762)